# How set knockout.js observable in select2-plugin with pre-defined Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I have this select2 input-field which I want to preset with the "tags"-option like this:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: myTags, select2: { tags: ko.toJS($root.Tags), minimumInputLength: 1, tokenSeparators: [',', ' '] }" />
```

where

```
self.Tags = ko.observableArray(dataFromServerCollectedWithGetJSON);
self.myTags = ko.observable();
```

Then of course I would like to input new tags so that the observable "myTags" contain the tags already existing in the database + new ones entered.
This has been an ongoing struggle for a while. As the myTags field with input from the autocomplete(based on "Tags"), deliver the "id"-field from the Tags-array, and new input, of course, is text strings. Thus I have 2 problems:
A) How to get "myTags" to register the names of the predefined Tags (and not only the id)
B) How to grab the value of "myTags" to use it in a db-save.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PM3QS/6/

NB: The "SelectedText"-context in the fiddle is due to how I want tags to be used in my application (with drop down-selected Textbatches).

Thanx for any help! :)

Comment: You are still supposed to supply a `selectedOptions` binding, I can see that nowhere in your fiddle. Compare to what the [author of `select2` did](http://jsfiddle.net/anasnakawa/6XvqX/381/).

Comment: I have looked at it, but it didm´t make me wiser. As I want to input my own tags I must use an <input> field, right? As far as I understand, the selectedOptions option is for the <select>, not?

Comment: Check out [this `select2Value` custom binding](http://jsfiddle.net/rMuK7/1/). I've removed all of your code that I thought was unconnected to your actual problem (which I perceive as "how to get the selected tags from a select2 box in "tag mode" - correct me if I'm wrong). Now there is an observable array that is updated in response to "change" events and contains everything the user selected. Is that of any help to you?

Comment: I think we are getting very close. :) 
Removing tags however does not remove them in the select2value-binding. Also, I´d like to set the id of new tags = "-1" and configure the "text"-attribute to for instance "TagName" or just "name"...

Comment: I guess you can't set the ID of new tags to `-1` uniformly. That way they would not be unique anymore. Just keep them at the initial (i.e. string-) value and once you post them to the server you can easily identify new tags with an `IsNumeric()` check and react accordingly. Setting new IDs on the client is futile anyway. The bug you noticed is fixed. I forgot to unwrap the observable array. http://jsfiddle.net/rMuK7/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @Tomalak! 
Appreciate it big time.
I struggle a bit with these observables and their context. :)

Comment: Yes, it takes some time getting used to. I also have a gut feeling that you are over-engineering things a little. I'm not sure what the purpose of all the things in your code is, but to me it looks you're doing things more complicated than necessary. — W/r/t the binding: Of course there are still issues with it. The integration with select2 isn't very solid. For example I haven't tested how it reacts to default values or API method calls (as opposed to keyboard entries). If it does what you need you can roll with it for now, but I'm sure it could use more tweaking.

Comment: I probably do overcomplicate it. On my page I first select a project (i.e. SelectedProject), then for the SelectedProject I can choose among Textbatches (i.e. SelectedText). Then for the SelectedText I want the Tags applied. Getting the different contexts right proves a challenge (see also my latest question) and that is why I created the fiddle as close to my context settings as possible.

Comment: So a Project contains many TextBatches, and a TextBatch contains many Tags, and those Tags are drawn from a common pool?

Comment: All Tags set on Textbatches is "accumulated" up to a Project-common pool. Say I have applied the Tag "Snow" in a former TextBatch. Then I want that Tag to be available and known when applying Tags on a new/different Textbatch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45501/discussion-between-tomalak-and-asle-g)